# Finding σ-Algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $Y(w)=\begin{cases}1,  & \text{if $w\in [0,1/3]$} \\2, & \text{if $w\in (1/3,1]$}  \end{cases}$

What is the $\sigma$-Algebra created by $Y$, $\sigma(Y)$?

I am kinda lost on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable $Y$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the following subsets:
$$
\left(\left\{\omega:Y(\omega)\leq x\right\}, x\in \mathbb R \right).
$$
It contains three elements for $x<1,1\leq x<2, x\geq 2$ which are $\emptyset,[0,\frac 13],[0,1]$. Therefore the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$ is:
$$
\sigma(Y)=\sigma\left(\left\{\emptyset,[0,\frac 13],[0,1]\right\}\right)=\left\{\emptyset,[0,\frac 13],(\frac 13,1],[0,1]\right\}.
$$